# Error Running mnist_softmax.py

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow

Nearly all my tensorflow scripts are ending with this error, what is causing it?

Code:

```
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py
```

What am I missing?

```
  C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users//AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users//AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py", line 78, in <module>
     tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
     sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
   File "C:/Users//AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py", line 37, in main
     mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py", line 211, in read_data_sets
     SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 142, in maybe_download
     gfile.Copy(temp_file_name, filepath)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 316, in copy
     compat.as_bytes(oldpath), compat.as_bytes(newpath), overwrite, status)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
     next(self.gen)
   File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
     pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: Read fewer bytes than requested

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Looks like it has to do with reading files in. How does it work if you read in the MNIST data yourself?

Comment: Also, this looks windows-specific. Googling the error message gave a GitHub commit. TF support for Windows is brand new, you may want to post an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 0.11 version? I also encountered some error with Master branch so I switch to the r0.11 branch